# How to distinguish a specific x bar color in a matplotlib bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently making a program in which one of the bars is for the client. I want this bar to be distinguished with a different color. I used to do this by iterating through the dictionary (barChartObjects) and when the key of the dictionary matched the argument (company) it would change the color. This happened as it plotted each bar individually and worked perfectly. Because of formatting issues with the labels, I had to switch up how I displayed the graphs and I am now stumped as to how I can do what I was previously with my new function.

```
def plotCompany(barChartObjects, company):
    # axis of data
    x = []
    y = []
    print("Company: " + company)
    # date for the file output name
    dateForOutput = date.today()
    # append the attributed input to the corresponding axis
    for key, value in barChartObjects.items():
        x.append(key)
        y.append(value)

    freq_series = pd.Series.from_array(y)
    # Plot the figure.
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

    # this is where I set the color for the graph, I am assuming I will need to change something here
    ax = freq_series.plot(kind='bar', color= "#36C989")

    ax.set_title("Total Shareholder Return (" + (date.today()-timedelta(days=30)).strftime("%b %d %Y") + ")")
    ax.set_xlabel("Companies")
    ax.set_ylabel("Percent Change")
    ax.set_xticklabels(x)

    plt.text(-0.25, 12, "Median: " + str(medianCalc(barChartObjects)) + "%")
    add_value_labels(ax)

    # save the file to my directory.
    plotDirectory = config.getDirectory(company)
    plt.savefig(plotDirectory, quality = 95)

    plt.show()
    return plotDirectory
```

Above is how my function is currently set up. For reference, below is the previous function I used which properly colored them but had wacky formatting, hence me using this new function.

```
def graphCompany(barChartObjects, company):
    # axis of data
    x = []
    y = []
    print("Company: " + company)
    # date for the file output name
    dateForOutput = date.today()
    # append the attributed input to the corresponding axis
    for key, value in barChartObjects.items():
        x.append(key)
        y.append(value)

    i = 0

    for key, value in barChartObjects.items():
        if (key == company):
            plt.bar(x[i], y[i],width = calcWidth(barChartObjects), color = "#289EE0")
            i = i + 1
        else:
            plt.bar(x[i], y[i],width = calcWidth(barChartObjects), color = "#36C989")
            i = i + 1

    # label the bar chart
    plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=None)
    plt.xlabel("Companies")
    plt.ylabel("Percent Change")
    plt.title("Total Shareholder Return (" + (date.today()-timedelta(days=30)).strftime("%b %d %Y") + ")")
    plt.text(-0.70, 9.25, "Median: " + str(medianCalc(barChartObjects)) + "%")


    # add labels to see the specific percent change for each x
    for a,b in zip(x, y):
        plt.text(a, b, str("%.2f" % b + "%"))



    # save the file to my directory.
    plotDirectory = config.getDirectory(company)
    plt.savefig(plotDirectory, quality = 95)
    plt.show()
    return plotDirectory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches seem complicated. If I understand correctly you want to plot a categorical bar chart with colors depending on the x axis category. As an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

companies = ["Company A", "Company B", "Company C", "Company D"]
values = [17, 23, 12, 32]

myclient = "Company B"
colors = ["grey" if company is not myclient else "red" for company in companies]

plt.bar(companies, values, color=colors)

plt.show()
```

[image]